# Why am I having trouble to embed "set syntax" into a file?

Tags: vim

I have read the help and examples, but still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

When I manually enter `:set syntax=javascript`, I get the syntax highlighting I want.

But when I edit the first line of my file to read:

```
/* vim: set syntax=javascript: */
```

nothing happens.

When I split that line into 3 lines:

```
/*
# vim: set syntax=javascript:
*/
```

I get some limited syntax highlighting, not as good as with manual command. I can write `syntax=anything` there and it makes no difference.

(Vim version 7.4.160, Centos 7)

Comment: Try `/* vim: filetype=javascript */`

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Unforunately it has no effect.

Comment: Probably should be `/* vim: set filetype=javascript */` -- you need the `set` keyword.

Comment: I tried that one and other tests. Vim shows that filetype or syntax is `conf` very probably based on the filename which is `somefile.conf`. Could it be possible that something overwrites the settings explicitely written in the file?

Comment: I temporarily removed /etc/vimrc, but it dit not help.

Comment: Do you have `modeline` turned on? Do `set modeline?` at the Vim ex prompt (`:`). If it says `nomodeline`, then you need a `set modeline` in your `.vimrc`. See `:help modeline` for details.

Comment: @JimStewart Thank you, Jim! You have solved it.

Comment: I added it as an answer with more details; please mark it if you're satisfied.

Comment: @JimStewart With pleasure. Just please don't tell anybody I'm using vi(m) since 1988.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines of the format:

```
/* vim: set syntax=javascript: */
```

are called *modelines* in Vim. In order for Vim to process them, you must have the `modeline` option toggled on.

To see if `modeline` is enabled, run this ex command:

```
:set modeline?
```

If it returns `nomodeline`, you can enable it by adding the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set modeline
```

Vim will look for a modeline in the first 5 lines of the file, by default. You can set the number of lines that will be searched with e.g.:

```
set modelines=10
```

See `:help modeline` for details.

Comment: BTW, the reason you probably saw some highlighting with your three-line comment format is probably because it saw the line beginning with `#` and decided that your filetype was `sh` or some other language, based on the syntax and a guess, and enabled syntax for the wrong type.